# Reuse a timer after cancelling

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I am developing an application which has to use timer for some purpose. What I need to do is, to set a timer when a condition satisfies and to cancel it correspondingly. Then again I may start the same timer which I cancelled. Please provide a solution.

Comment: you cannot use the same timer. So need to create a new instance of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single timer android sets a single thread. When you cancel that timer its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it. So you have to create a new instance of the timer object. 
you can do as shown below.

```
 if(condition == true)
{ 
timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask(), delay, span);
}
else{
   timer.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `CountDownTimer` class like:

```
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
                public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                     // do something of finish timer
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // do something on tick of timer
            }
        }
```

and should make an object of MyTimer like below:

```
MyCount timerCount = new MyCount(<TIME_UNTIL_FINISH_MILLISECONDS>, <TIME_OF_EACH_TICK>);
```

and can start timer everywhere you want with:

```
timerCount.start();
```

and cancel it with:

```
timerCount.cancel();
```